# Need help for File Upload between webserver and file server in amazon

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I Have two separate window based instances in Amazon EC2. 
(a) Web Server (b) File Server

In Web Server, i hosted a NET application under IIS. I have a asp.net file upload control and i want to upload file to File Server by using this control. but when i am trying it is showing
Network path is not found error. I am using below command.

FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("@"\server ip\Uploaded\"));

Thanks in Advance.